# Is there a way to increase the amount of time a compressed spring takes to depress/go back to a relaxed state?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

How would a person slow down the time it takes a compression spring to enter a relaxed state from a compressed state?

Answer (score 3):

Add some kind of damping element. This is regularly done when you require a spring to isolate vibrations, i.e. in a car suspension:

[image]

The damping element slows down the relaxation of the spring and at the same time dissipates energy to reduce oscillations.

Comment: They're often used interchangeably, but in this context "damping" is arguably a more precise term than "dampening" - note the figure is labelled as a "damper", not a "dampener".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: Thanks, corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

- insert it in oil
- cool it down with liquid nitrogen

Comment: When cooling down a spring in liquid nitrogen in most materials the stiffness increases, the spring constant goes up and you will observe the opposite effect: the frequency of the oscillation increases!